# Windows 7 64bit crash during gameplay. Caused by drivers ntoskrnl.exe and hal.dll

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod

I'm having trouble with a computer that I built a little less than a year ago (Christmas 2012). I have just recently been getting the blue screen of death while playing Banner's new expansion called Chivalry: Deadliest Warrior.

The BSOD only occurs while playing the game and it has happened 4 times today. I've downloaded a program called BlueScreenView from www.nirsoft.net and it is showing me that the first 3 crashes were caused by the driver hal.dll and the 4th was caused by the driver ntoskrnl.exe.

I'm unsure of what to do now as my knowledge of computer software is very limited. I have run across a couple of things on the internet, like re-install the VGA driver, but that doesn't seem like the answer because in the report I have generated it is telling me that Microsoft developed all 4 of these drivers and they are part of the operating system (not NVIDIA). Below are copies of the blue screen report. Can anyone help me?

**ntoskrnl.exe**

111513-5912-02.dmp  11/15/2013 8:11:55 PM   DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL   0x000000d1  00000000`0000007d   00000000`00000006   00000000`00000008   00000000`0000007d   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+75bc0  NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.18247 (win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75bc0                  C:\Windows\Minidump\111513-5912-02.dmp  4   15  7601    293,416 11/15/2013 8:12:31 PM

**hal.dll**

111513-5912-01.dmp  11/15/2013 12:31:17 AM      0x00000124  00000000`00000000   fffffa80`070ef028   00000000`be200000   00000000`0005110a   hal.dll hal.dll+12a3b   Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75bc0                  C:\Windows\Minidump\111513-5912-01.dmp  4   15  7601    293,400 11/15/2013 12:31:46 AM

Comment: What graphic s card do you have?

Comment: GeForce GTX 660

Comment: What version are your Nvidia drivers?

Comment: upload the 2 dump files from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\Minidump to your desktop, zip the fodler and upload the zip to your dropbox/skydrive account and post the link here. Also use @my name to notify me when you reply to me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not really that the problem is in ntoskrnl or hal, but rather that the crash simply shows that module.  The most likely reason is overheating during gameplay, but faulty video drivers can also cause such crashes.

Remedy usually is:

- Try newer drivers, especially from the chipset mfr
- Adjust video settings
- Run a program to monitor temperatures of the CPU & system, and ensure that it's not over-heating during gameplay (which is very common.)

Seriously:  the MS-developed drivers are usually -not- better than the chipset mfr's drivers.  MS provides a baseline driver and rarely updates it;  the chipset companies fix bugs and provide new releases.  So given what you posted, you probably should prioritize updating the driver to the latest & best for the card you have.

Additionally, your problems seem common with that card.  This thread: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/619501/bsod-irql_not_less_or_equal/
contains a post from someone who has had better results by turning off vsync and anti aliasing.  That is certainly worth trying.

Comment: Debra, Thanks for answering me. I have current drivers, both for my GPU and from my chipset mfr (intel); I have adjusted the vdeo settings to turn off VSYNC and anti-aliasing, and now I've just installed a monitor program and tested my computer while running the game.

Comment: I'm very surprised to say that, according to this program HWMonitor my teperatures reach the maximum value after about 5 minutes of gameplay. So I'm guessing the problem is overheating. My CPU is under a desk, which has little airflow, I have given the CPU some space from the side of the desk to let it breathe however I guess I need to move it to another place as no air is getting in there.

Comment: Debra, I have now placed my CPU in a cooler place, reinstalled Chivalry Medieval Warfare, turned off VSYNC and anti-aliasing, and turned off Microsoft security essentials, (each option exclusive from the other) and I just now got a blue screen. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Are there fans on your card?  If so, have you checked them?  Is there a utility you can use to monitor the card temps?  With this specific card, I think you really need to look at the drivers if your temps are OK, but it's very telling that it comes up while you are gaming & "stressing" the card.  Also if your temps are too high, a quick fix -may- be to simply add a case fan or two.